# How to specify Kusto client request properties in ADF copy activity

Tags: azure-data-factory, azure-data-explorer, kql

How to pass the [queryconsistency client request property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/concepts/queryconsistency#controlling-query-consistency) = 'weakconsistency' when the source of ADF copy activity is an Azure Data Explorer dataset?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try adding the [queryconsistency](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/api/netfx/request-properties#clientrequestproperties-options) client property to your query, e.g.:

```
set queryconsistency = 'weakconsistency';
print 1+2 // replace with your own query
```